# Subclasses of collection in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, collections, subclass

I am studying Collections in Java. What exactly are the subclasses of a Collection? Are they ArrayList, Lists, etc?

Comment: See this diagram from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework#/media/File:Java.util.Collection_hierarchy.svg

Comment: Basically, yes.  You can't give a definitive list, since *anyone* can declare a class or interface that derives from the `Collection` interface.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection` us an interface,  not a class, so pedantically it has no sub classes. Rather, it has classes that implement it, and interfaces that extend it. As it is a `public` interface,  *anyone* could,  in principle, write a class that implements it. So it is impossible to list all those classes.

Answer (score 0):

As Raedwald pointed out, `Collection` is an interface so classes implement it rather than subclass it. The Java documentation lists the Java classes that implement it. I feel like that might be what you're looking for: [Java 8 Collection Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)